# Does Beskar armor resist lightsabers?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-mandalorian

In S2, E5, when Din Djarin (the Mandalorian of the title) fights against a Jedi, his Beskar armor is able to fully protect him from slashes from a lightsaber.

Is this a new concept introduced by Disney's *The Mandalorian* or has it been this way from the original Lucas's *Star Wars* universe?

I was under the impression a lightsaber could cut through anything but another lightsaber.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_iron

Comment: [Cortosis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cortosis/Legends) is another material that affects lightsabers. It actually shorts them out.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226307/whats-the-strength-of-beskar-vs-a-lightsaber

Comment: It's something Karen Traviss came up with.

Answer (score 2):

Beskar is newly introduced concept, it's **not** in the original series. It's able to resist light-Sabres but it can't effectively the Arc-Light Generator which heats up the armour until the person it is protecting is fried.

Comment: It's not all that new - Mandalorian Iron was first mentioned about 20 years ago or so, back in the literature that is now called Legends. It got the name Beskar a few years later - long before the TV show. I don't have a good source for its endurance against lightsabres, though Wookiepedia implies that is older than the show, too.

Comment: Star Wars canon is complex - even after Disney took over. And they've elevated book canon into TV and movies a fair bit.

Comment: Worth pointing out that there is nothing in the OT or PT that indicates Beskar *can't* protect against a light saber. In the one instance that we see of Mandalorian armor in close combat with a light saber, Mace Windu swings once and beheads Jango Fett, striking his neck, which was not protected by Beskar.

Comment: @ruffdove: Every armour has its Achilles heel. I wonder where they got that idea from?

Comment: LOL! I see what you did there.